# assign unique id based on each new instance of a value, and assign same ID to subsequent repeated values

Tags: r

Looking to do something like this in R, but need to assign the same value to subsequent '0' values following each new instance of '1'.  So my data looks like this:

```
Val
  1
  0
  0
  0
  1
  0
  1
  0
  0 
  0
  0
```

and need to assign unique id to look like this:

```
 Val  ID
  1    1
  0    1
  0    1
  0    1
  1    2
  0    2
  1    3
  0    3
  0    3
  0    3
  0    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
df$ID <- cumsum(df$Val)
```

**Output**

```
   Val ID
1    1  1
2    0  1
3    0  1
4    0  1
5    1  2
6    0  2
7    1  3
8    0  3
9    0  3
10   0  3
11   0  3
```

Comment: Simply sophisticated.  appreciate it, Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `zoo`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Val) %>% #Grouping by Val
 mutate(temp = ifelse(Val == 0, NA, sequence(n()))) %>% #Assigning NA if Val is zero, otherwise creating a sequence around the ones
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(ID = na.locf(temp)) %>% #Filling the NAs with the last non-NA case
 select(-temp)

     Val   ID
   <int> <int>
 1     1     1
 2     0     1
 3     0     1
 4     0     1
 5     1     2
 6     0     2
 7     1     3
 8     0     3
 9     0     3
10     0     3
11     0     3
```